# Windows permissions error

Tags: server, windows

Anyone experienced with  issues setting up Craft on Windows server - getting phperror logs within Craft stating:

`The directory is not writable by the Web process for cpresources`

I have got the hosts to update the permissions for this folder but still throwing this error. Oddly Craft has no problem writing to the storage folder where these logs are stored and a similar set-up on the same server is working fine.

Comment: Plenty of experience on Windows/IIS, but still seems like a permissions/IIS configuration error to me? Whatever user account the App Pool is running as for that site needs the write permissions.

Comment: Thanks Brad - client (who manages the hosting) has made some changes to the permissions and all seems to be working now. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome... would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?